# Pass variables to drupal template

Tags: drupal

I need to display a page in drupal that is created by a template and based on a specific record from my table.

I created the module "item" (as an example).

I made the item_menu hook:

```
  $items['items/%item'] = array(
    'title' => 'Items',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('show_item', 1),
    'access callback' => true,
    'access arguments' => array(),
  );
```

I created a load function for the item:

```
function item_load($itemid)
{
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM {items} it WHERE it.id = :itemid';

  $result = db_query(
    $sql, 
    array(':itemid' => $itemid), 
    array( 'target' => 'mydatabase' ));

  $item = $result->fetchObject();
  return $item;
}
```

Now I want to use a template to display the specifics for the item, so I made a item module
a item.tpl.php. and a item_theme hook to register the template:

```
function item_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) 
{
  return array(
    'show_item' => array(
      'template' => 'item',
      'variables' => array(),
    ),
  );
}
```

The final thing I need to do is pass the item object to the item.tpl.php so I can display the item properties.

But I don't know how to do this. How can I make the item known within the template??

I hope the question is clear enough. Thanks in advance.

[edit]

I found that arg(1) contains the value of the wildcard from the menu page arguments, should I use arg(1) to look up the item in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the names and default values for the vars you want to use in the `variables` part of your array in `hook_theme`:

```
function item_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'show_item' => array(
      'template' => 'item',
      'variables' => array('var1' => NULL, 'var2' => NULL, 'etc...'),
    ),
  );
}
```

Then call the theme function like this:

```
$item_output = theme('show_item', array('var1' => $a_var, 'var2' => $another_var));
```

** UPDATE **

To address the `load()` function being called 4 times you can use static vars to avoid the query being run every time:

```
function item_load($itemid) {
  $items = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__, array());

  if (!isset($items[$itemid])) {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM {items} it WHERE it.id = :itemid';
    $items[$itemid] = db_query(
      $sql, 
      array(':itemid' => $itemid),
      array('target' => 'mydatabase')
    )->fetchObject();
  }

  return $items[$itemid];
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use theme(), because I than need to define the whole page layout myself. When I use drupal_get_form the standard page template is used and only the 'item' part is done by the item template. Or can I use theme() and still have the standard page template?

Comment: Using `theme()` has nothing to do with the overall page layout really, it basically just makes use of Drupal's theme registry system so that other modules/themes can override the output. For example you can use `theme('image', array('uri' => 'some/path'));` to output a themed image, which has absolutely no effect on the page as a whole.

Comment: Oeps, you are right. I came to that conclusion because I just did theme('show_item') instead of return theme('show_item').

Comment: Ok, I rewrote the code using your sollution and it is working! Thanks a lot. I noticed that the load function for the item is being called 4 times. Do you have any idea why that is?

Comment: This happens to me a fair bit and I'm not always entirely sure why, I've updated the answer to include the `drupal_static` pattern for your load function which will minimise database usage when this does happen

Comment: Ok thanks. What do you think about my sollution, to not use the load function to get the item, but to get the item in the function where I call theme() and use args(1) to access the item id? That way I can be sure the database is only accessed 1 time.

Comment: That's perfectly fine as long as you only plan on using your theme on a page that *has* that id in the URL. If it's only ever used on the node/entity view page then you should be ok